# Styling MUI Tab Icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, themes, styled-components

How can I apply custom styles for the Tab Icon?

```
export default function EcomTabs(props) {
  return (
    <Tabs textColor="primary">
      <Tab
        sx={{ textTransform: "none", color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[50],
      }}
        icon={props.icon}
        label={props.label}
      ></Tab>
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

1. tried to create a new theme for the component:

```
components: {
        MuiTabs: {
            iconWrapper: {
                color: "secondary",
            }

                },
        },
```

2. also tried to use StyledTab, but didn't work as well

created styled tab in separated filed

```
const StyledTab = styled(Tab)  (({ theme }) => ({
    "& .MuiTab-root": {
        ".MuiTab-iconWrapper" :{
            color: theme.palette.primary.main,
        },
    },
}));
```

and imported to component

````
export default function EcomTabs(props) {
  return (
    <Tabs textColor="primary">
      <StyledTab
        sx={{ textTransform: "none", color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[50],
      }}
        icon={props.icon}
        label={props.label}
      ></StyledTab>
    </Tabs>
  );
}```
````